# Design Pattern - File Generation and Options

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have a class that generates a text file.

It is very simple class that has methods for:

creating file,
opening file
closing file
saving file
writing to file
etc
etc

There are some options i use when writing my text to file such as font size, color and max words.

These options are passed to the constructor.

Should I split this class in to two seperated classes:

fileMaker
fileMakerOptions

and use fileMakerOptions object hold responsibility for text size etc and pass to the constructor of fileMaker?

or would it be best to have file maker encapsulate everything related to making the file including the style options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your class is simple. And if there are only few options. Then no, you should not create new class. Overrefactoring is very bad.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more information about your main class responsibility as far as count of options you want to handle. Anyway - the general idea of creating new additional instances is delete options handling responsibility from your main 'class' responsibility.

For me I decide, if the amount of options greater then 4-5 - then I creating separate option entity.

Answer (score 0):

I only split up classes when an existing class becomes too difficult or gettign too many properties of functions OR when I know beforehand that it will be extended a lot.

In your case it depends on the complexity and amount of functions/properties.